# Why I faced a problem with running pytorch in vscode?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I installed environment throughout Conda , run a simple code in PyCharm and did not face any problem.

But when I start trying to run same code in VScode, I had a problem. I picked up right environment, when running this script on terminal in vscode, its working.

[working in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8080.png) But when I try to run file with same code

```
import torch
x = torch.rand(3)
print(x)
```

It shows the following problem

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'`

[not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE074.png)

Comment: How did you run this file?

Comment: In the right top I press play button and choose Run code

Comment: Hey there, it sounds like a classic environment confusion. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_environments Vscode allow you to choose which env you would like to use ti run your code.
I believe you need to choose the conda env

Comment: IMHO, I believe vscode is using the default python interpreter that ships on mac and not the python interpreter you have with conda. The default one is not aware of all the libraries the other one has.

Comment: I chose a right environment as I chose same in pycharm( where my code is working). But something still wrong.

Comment: This error arise when the python interpreter can not find the module. which led me to believe you did not use the conda interpreter. Could you run add this line to you python code and run it ? `help('modules')` it should print all the packages the current interpreter has access to. Could you put the result in you question ?